# Rails + Javascript + Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm using a template that I bought and I'm having this issue:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'peity' in unicorn.dashboard.js:11
```

and this is line 11:

```
unicorn.peity();
```

On my manifest file I got this:

```
//= require admins/cms/excanvas.min
//= require admins/cms/jquery.min
//= require admins/cms/jquery.ui.custom
//= require admins/cms/jquery.uniform
//= require admins/cms/jquery.flot.min
//= require admins/cms/jquery.flot.resize.min
//= require admins/cms/jquery.dataTables.min
//= require admins/cms/jquery.gritter.min
//= require admins/cms/jquery.validate

//= require admins/cms/jquery.peity

//= require admins/cms/jquery.wizard
//= require admins/cms/select2.min
//= require admins/cms/fullcalendar.min
//= require admins/cms/bootstrap.min
//= require admins/cms/bootstrap-colorpicker
//= require admins/cms/bootstrap-datepicker
//= require admins/cms/unicorn

//= require admins/cms/unicorn.dashboard

//= require admins/cms/unicorn.form_common
//= require admins/cms/unicorn.form_validation
//= require admins/cms/unicorn.wizard
//= require admins/cms/unicorn.interface
//= require admins/cms/unicorn.tables
//= require admins/cms/unicorn.charts
//= require admins/cms/unicorn.calendar
```

This is how the scripts are loaded in the static index.html that came with the template:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.uniform.js"></script>
<script src="js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/unicorn.js"></script>
<script src="js/unicorn.form_common.js"></script>
```

And this is how my dashboard index scripts are loaded:

```
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/excanvas.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/jquery.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/jquery.ui.custom.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/jquery.uniform.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/jquery.flot.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/jquery.flot.resize.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/jquery.dataTables.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/jquery.gritter.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/jquery.validate.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/jquery.peity.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/jquery.wizard.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/select2.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/fullcalendar.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/bootstrap-colorpicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/bootstrap-datepicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/unicorn.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/unicorn.dashboard.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/unicorn.form_common.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/unicorn.form_validation.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/unicorn.wizard.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/unicorn.interface.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/unicorn.tables.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/unicorn.charts.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admins/cms/unicorn.calendar.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The weird thing is that unicorn.dashboard is getting loaded after jquery.peity. Another extrange thing is that when I open the index.html that came with the template it doesn't get this error at all. I'm not sure what the problem could be. I been trying for hours to figure this out but I had no luck at all.

It would be so helpful if someone could help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript references that are in the plain index.html that's working? I suspect something is missing from your asset pipeline, or is using different versions of the files. Also, it might be useful to remove the unicorn requires and insert your own console.log($("body").peity) to make sure peity is actually being loaded.

Comment: There you are Dan, I updated my comment. After doing console.log($"body").peity) I get a function and undefined in the last row in chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

If you (temporarily) change your manifest to exactly match the index.html file, do things work?

If so, I suspect conflicts between peity, unicorn and something else that's included, possibly explorecanvas.